# how can i add online image in libreoffice write?

Tags: libreoffice

Does LibreOffice have its own library of online images to insert into Writer, etc? I’m thinking of how Microsoft Word, when you go to Insert an image, you can directly choose from an online library of images from Microsoft, so it’s safer than choosing random images from unknown websites, and it’s more convenient. If such a thing doesn’t yet exist in LibreOffice, this would be a perfect opportunity for artists to whip up some images in open source software like GIMP!

Comment: you have not mentioned any version or distro of Ubuntu here. Your question may be better directed at https://ask.libreoffice.org/tags/c/english/5/writer

Comment: Get control of  it. I've done this many times and the easiest way to do it is to insert the image in LibreOffice Writer as a background image with *Format* -> *Page Style* -> *Area* tab -> click *Image* button -> *Style* dropdown menu select *Stretched* -> click *Add / Import*. The image will automatically stretch to fit.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/The_Gallery_LibreOffice:

> The Gallery is a library containing objects (pictures or sounds), which you can easily insert into your documents.
>
> It is available in all Components of LibreOffice.
>
> To open the Gallery, select View ▸ Sidebar menu ( Ctrl + F5 ) and click on the Sidebar tab "Gallery".

On my system, the menu option is *View → Gallery*.